# Issue with passing objects to domain method

Tags: wcf-ria-services, invoke, dto, domainservices

I have WCF Ria Services App with DTO objects. I defined relations between my DTO objects:

```
[Include] 
    [Association("FK_Items_OrderID", "ID", "OrderID")] 
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

So I can see collection of Items on the client and operate with it. Then I want to save changes and call this method:

```
 [Invoke]
    public void SaveOrderChanges(Order order)
    {
        _dataManager.SaveOrderChanges(order);
    }
```

It is domain service method. But I see than collection of related Items in Order object here is already NULL, but when I call this method on the client and pass order to this method collection is filled.

Does anybody know what to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's happen because the client side serializer don't include assocations. Wcf ria services has a different way to handle this kind of scenarious, but this involves the use of DomainContext and the standard Get/Insert/Update/Delete methods.
My advice is to change the sign of your save method to something like

```
[Invoke]
public void SaveOrderChanges(string serializedOrder)
{
    Order order = MyCustomSerializer.Deserialize<Order>(serializedOrder);
    _dataManager.SaveOrderChanges(order);
}
```

Thi`s is an utilities class that I use to serialize and deserialize objects, however it should be tricked to include the Items collection.

```
public static class Serialization
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        //Create a stream to serialize the object to.
        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        // Serializer the User object to the stream.
        var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (T));


        ser.WriteObject(ms, obj);
        byte[] array = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array, 0, array.Length);
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string obj) where T : class
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (T));
        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(obj));
        var result = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as T;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to do the opposite client-side and serialize your order and items. 
This is the easiest way to go that I know, however you could also take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/24/wcf-extensibility-custom-serialization-in-silverlight.aspx).
Eventually, try to refactor your code in the way WCF Ria is meant to go (Context based)

Hope this helps,
Marco